# Detecting ETH and Token deposits on an address and/or multiple contract addresses

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Many questions have been asked here but mostly they have been vague questions and/or answers so before marking as duplicate please read this one as its completely specific.

I have an ether account that deploys multiple forwarder contracts to be used as unique deposit addresses for the public, just like an exchange.
I need to detect all the deposits made to these contract addresses or to the one main ether address.

Possible solution was to use web3 subscriptions as documented [web3.eth.subscribe](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html) but the code(below) given as example doesn't log any deposits/transactions made to the account address to be honest it doesn't log any relevant information when it comes to logging the data with the contract address and/or account address. I tried removing all the filters and seeing all the logs, made a deposit to contract address but it never logged anything related to my account or contract address or the sender address for that matter.

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});

// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
    if(success)
        console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

References:

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1752
[How to programmatically detect and accept ETH and ERC20 deposits](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/how-to-programmatically-detect-and-accept-eth-and-erc20-deposits)
[How to detect ETH deposits into an Ether address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39275/how-to-detect-eth-deposits-into-an-ether-address)

I believe it was quite simple when it was `web3.eth.filter` but since web3 1.0 this is no more an option.

So what is the current recommended method for listening to the deposits?

Comment: I think you're still gonna have a problem with "Internal" transactions. AFAIK, Web3 doesn't detect these.

Comment: but it should detect the incoming deposits to a contract address (it's a forwarder contract). also is there some utility in some other language that does this in a more reliable manner, i would happily implement that as well.

Comment: yes, "normal" txs should be detected just fine, but not "internal". i believe this is the same for all clients in any language. see here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6432/20276

Comment: @nyusternie but I am unable to detect the normal eth transaction that is sent from an eth account (completely separate) to a forwarder contract address.

Comment: I don't know if Web3 can do what you want, but I've used [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#events) to subscribe for balance changes and it works great! But again, this WILL NOT detect "internal" txs, so its very likely your balance can become out of sync with your event updates.

Comment: @nyusternie a transaction sent from an eth account (eg metamask) to an contract deployed on a completely different node is an internal txn or external txn. the contract and account have no relationship to each other.

Comment: sent from metamask, myetherwallet, etc is "normally" `external`. `internal` is when using one of those services to send eth **FROM** a smart contract (eg. `<address>.transfer(<amount>)`) and those are not detected by any of the Web3 libraries I've seen. i'm fairly certain that block explorers like Etherscan are using custom nodes and recording that info into a separate db. unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to do that myself, so I really can't help you there.

Comment: see that's the issue I am not able to detect the external transaction that i send using metamask to another address on a my node.

Comment: oh! did you try Ethers? https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#id6 take a look at the 2nd example. its worked perfectly for me in the past. if you still have issue with it, let me know I'll writeup an EthFiddle that you can experiment with.